# Replace multiple try catches with a single global try catch block

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling

I am trying to aim for a global `try catch` exception handler as I have several child class
methods that have try catches inside them. So basically I want the parent class method to catch all those 
exceptions and log it.

One of the common ones are SQL exceptions.

What is the best approach here to create a common handler which will catch the errors?

Here is an example of what is going on in my application

```
public class Parent
{
    public void ParentMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var childClass = new Child();
            var process = childClass.Process();
            if (process)
            {
                // Do this
            }
            else
            {
                // raise new Exception
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            WriteToErrorLogger.Error(ex)
        }       
    }
}
```

```
public class Child
{
    public bool Process()
    {
        try{
            // Do something and save to Database
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            // log exception
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log exception
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless I’m misunderstanding, can’t you just remove all the child try catches and use the parent level one? All exceptions inherit from `Exception` so they will all be caught there without needing to specify each exception type.

Comment: Ok but how would I know which class raised the error if I was to extend the error handling?

Comment: The stack trace will tell you. There are other ways to find out but that’s the simplest

Comment: May as well let the exception crash your entire process.

Comment: If you just want a global exception handler, put it in the `main` method of your program.  This is a really difficult question to answer well without knowing the real-life context of your code.  In general you should only catch exceptions when you can actually do something about them or at unit-of-work boundaries if you don't want the exception to cause your application to fail completely.

Comment: Having try/catch on parent method will throw exception on the child methods by default yet, It is not recommended to depend on that as the parent method may/will lose the trace of child methods at some points as running async tasks or methods with callbacks to another function which will cause your program to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean? What would make sense would be to do the exact opposite

```
public class Parent
{
    public void ParentMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            var childClass = new Child();
            var process = childClass.Process();
            if (process)
            {
                // Do this
            }
            else
            {
                // raise new Exception
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            WriteToErrorLogger.Error(ex);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            WriteToErrorLogger.Error(ex);
        }       
    }
}
```

Child

```
public class Child
{
    public bool Process()
    {
            // Do something and save to Database       
    }
}
```

If you want to conditionally do it, you could change the child like this

```
public class Child
{
    public bool Process(bool rethrow = false)
    {
        try{
            // Do something and save to Database
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {
            if(rethrow) throw;
            // log exception
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if(rethrow) throw
            // log exception
            return false;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Athanasios. If I go with the first suggestion then how will I know which `Child` class raised the exception i.e. if I wanted to log detailed exception of which class raised it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.source?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: There is the Source property of the exception object. And since the `SqlException` and every exception inherits from `Exception` it is available in every catch clause.

Comment: Thanks @Athanasios I will accept this as answer